# php zipfile returning an empty zip file

Tags: php

```
<?php

$files = array('1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt');
$zipname = 'test.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);

?>
```

this is my code, the only issue is it is not downloading the files i have specified.

am i doing something wrong? is it the browser im using? (opera)

the file downloads but it ends up being empty.

Comment: Have you verified the contents of the zip file? Maybe using `file_get_contents()` to dump it? Also, what value does `filesize($zipname)` return?

Comment: echo file_get_contents($zipname) causes a 500. echo filesize($zipname) returns nothing.

Comment: I just tried this in my local development environment, no issues. I get a zip file and it extracts on chrome.

Comment: It sounds like your zip file isn't getting created properly. What's the return value of the `$zip->open(...)` call? It should be `true` on success.

Comment: how would i get the return value?

Comment: `$success = $zip->open(...); var_dump($success);`

Comment: $success = $zip->open(); var_dump($success); returns NULL

Comment: Sounds like there's a few weird things going on. `null` [isn't a normal return type](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php) of `ZipArchive::open`. Do you have error reporting turned on? I imagine you're probably getting some PHP notices or warnings that are currently being suppressed.

Comment: the php server is not run by me only the code, so sadly i could not tell you. if you could give me a redone answer (something that works) it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First check zip file is creating or not and then,

Add File transfer header...

```
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' ."Your file size" );            
        set_time_limit(0);
```

It will work.

Append "Your file size" to the length of the file size.

Comment: this just returns the page name but as a 0kb file :( i feel like im doing something wrong up top. manually setting sizes is not needed as they are made during the creation of the zip file? also i need to be able to change between many files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't know why, but when I change the logic to use `addFromString` instead of `addFile` PHP generated the ZIP file as expected.